# UI calendar shows wrong week number

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon, calendar

Does anybody know why would the calendar show the wrong week number (a number less -> 15 instead of 16):

[image]

Whereas the current week is 16... The interesting thing is that `date +%V` command in the terminal returns me the correct number 16. So, it's not like the fault is in the core of the system or something like that.

I can live with that, of course, but it is just interesting why is that happening.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on localization. Not everyone agrees on what "week 1" is in a year. In Holland for instance week 1 starts when it has 4 or more days in that year (so week 1 is that week where the 1st Thursday is in the new year). But other countries start week 1 on Jan 1st or on the 1st Monday that is in the new year. And you can get a deviation of 1 between the methods used.

My clock (using Dutch localization):

[image]

Check "settings" "Language support" "Regional formats" for what you are using. Mine is set to "Netherlands". Then check on-line how for that country week 1 is defined.

Comment: Using French localization on Linux Mint 17, I have a similar issue: the calendar applet tells me"week 13" for both the week starting on March 23rd and the one starting on March 30th. @Milkncookiez can you confirm?

Comment: No, I can not. Mint is off topic and I have never ever used it.

Comment: I wanted to know if you had the same issue since Mint is Ubuntu based. Week numbers are OK until the 13th week, and KO after.

Comment: What you describe seems a bug to me.

Comment: I think so, and I am wondering if it is Mint-only related or Ubuntu related. Since the issue @Milkncookiez describes above concerns April, perhaps March is OK on his system, as it is on mine.